# Why does the hot side of the JWST vary so much?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, lagrangian-points, temperature

Usually the a sensor is in the low $50s$, yesterday it was $38^\circ C$, and today it is $55^\circ C$. Was it a measuring/reporting anomaly or does it really change that much?

Here is the link to current temperature data:

https://webb.nasa.gov/content/webbLaunch/whereIsWebb.html?units=metric

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? Can you include a link so others can have a look?

Comment: https://webb.nasa.gov/content/webbLaunch/whereIsWebb.html?units=metric

I look at least once a day.

Comment: It looks like you are watching the sensor on the sunshield, not the one on the spacecraft body. Can you confirm that? If that's true, then my best guess is that they are tilting the spacecraft for some reason. It'd be nice to see it graphed vs time.

Comment: Yes. The "a" sensor is on the shield and it was the one that changed while the others remained mostly static. Although until yesterday, it was pretty static, too. The cold side is getting gradually colder.

And yeah, I would like to see the historical data to make sure I didn't imagine the change.

And they just added 5 more sensor readings ...